# The follow count for proposals is inconsistent with the list of followers

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, followers

The follow count for proposal "[Bicycles](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2305/bicycles)" seems to be out of sync with actual number of followers (see screenshot below). The count is zero in all the views I have seen, including the main page and stats page (if it is followed).

Is this a bug?

[image: Screendump from the 'Bycycles' proposal on Area51, illustrating the non-consistent count]

Comment: There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things.

Comment: Interesting.  I saw that proposal on the main page but never clicked on it.  At the time, I assumed that the proposer wasn't interested in bicycles but assumed that others would be, and unfollowed the proposal after creating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed.  If new people sign up for the site, we don't count them as followers until they have verified their email address.  However, they were still showing up in the list of followers.

Comment: Whatever the fix was, looks like it was undone at some point, and now the bug is back. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238807/they-seem-to-be-following-a-proposal-but-are-not-counted

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if this could get fixed, or at least clarified.  I have a proposal that currently says 16 followers in the top-left orange box, but the recent followers list shows 21 users.  It would be good to know what the real number is.  Do I have 16 followers or 21?  Do I need put more efforts into attracting followers than I'm already planning?  A lower count on the proposal master list could have a negative effect on the proposal, leading people to think it's less popular than it really is.

My SWAG is that it's some kind of hybrid between caching and denormalization in the database.

**EDIT:**
Thinking that this might be a bug now.  Looking at all of the profiles of the users who are following my proposal, it shows that they still are following it.  The "Following" count has gone from 20 down to 16 today for whatever reason.

**EDIT2**
Ah, ok.  Now the list is synced up with the follow count so it must be a caching thing.  Dang, lost some followers then.

Comment: What is SWAG?  SomeWhat educAted Guess?

Comment: @Popular: more or less.  Scientific Wild @$$ Guess.

Comment: is there any other kind?