# Area 51 is miscounting my proposal followers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51, followers

I know of one person who is following my proposal who doesn't show up on the proposal webpage.

My proposal is for quantitative finance: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/117/quantitative-finance.  It shows 19 people following the proposal (on the side of the page), and the total listed at the top of the page is 19 followers.  Yet one user is not listed: http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/89/dirk-eddelbuettel.  This makes me wonder if other followers are also not being counted?

Comment: @David by design indeed, but it's misleading as it appears to the user as if he's following the proposal and it's showing in his profile. Can something be done about it please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Users are only counted as followers if they've [verified their email address](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52213/follow-count-for-proposals-are-inconsistent-with-the-list-of-followers/53063#53063). The user you link to has not.