# They seem to be following a proposal but are not counted

Tags: bug, area-51, site-proposal

I was looking at one of the examples on the Arabic Language proposal, I noticed [a user and clicked on him/her](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/116627/user1298069) to look at their profile, on there I noticed he/she were following the proposal I reopened ([StackOverflow (in Arabic)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75879/stackoverflow-in-arabic)) but the follower count only says one (me).  Is this a bug? or is it that this user followed the un-followed the proposal and his profile isn't updated?

Comment: Most likely [an old bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52213/follow-count-for-proposals-are-inconsistent-with-the-list-of-followers), that has returned.

Answer (score 2):

That user has 101 reputation points from an association bonus; and as you get 50 reputation points if you confirm your email address on Area 51, we can be sure that he didn't.

After a quick look at other unconfirmed (101 or 1 rep) users who committed to/followed a proposal, it looks like unconfirmed users aren't included in the list of committers/followers.